# Fetch Eager NHibernate failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

Im dealing with N+1 problem, and I want to eager load a collection in an especific query, but I am getting the "failed to lazily initialize a collection" error, or the query keep lazy loading.

I have tried many suggestions given by stackmembers but none worked.

My entity example:

```
public class Bar
{
   private _IList<Foo> _fooList;
   public IEnumerable<Foo> FooList {get{return _fooList;} }
}
```

The map example:

```
HasMany(d => d.FooList)
                .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
                .KeyColumn("IdBar")
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Inverse();
```

Queries that throws error (failed to lazily initialize a collection):

```
var test = GetSession().Query<Bar>()
                .Fetch(b => b.FooList);

IList<Bar> bars= GetSession().QueryOver<Bar>()
                .Fetch(d => d.FooList).Eager
                .List();
```

Query that still with N+1 problem:

```
        IList<Bar> bars= GetSession().QueryOver<Bar>()
            .Fetch(d => d.FooList).Eager
            .JoinQueryOver<Foo>(d => d.FooList)
            .Where(f => f.Active).List<Bar>();

        Foo fooAlias = null;
        IList<Bar> bars= GetSession().QueryOver<Bar>()
            .Fetch(d => d.FooList).Eager
            .JoinAlias(d => d.FooList, () => fooAlias)
            .List();
```

I need help to solve this N+1 problem, eager loading the FooList collection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used HQL along with `... LEFT JOIN FETCH ...`? Did it provide same issues too?

Comment: No, I dont know how to use HQL yet. I will search for it

Comment: It's better to use HQL according my experiences as sometimes it's hard to model some kind of queries in fluent approach. I would use HQL and solve the problem later once it would happen also in it.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping should use

```
.Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField
```

instead.